# Calling delay() while iterating with `each()`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to stagger the rate at which a few objects fade into view. I'm not sure what I've got wrong.

From the docs, it looks like I simply call it like any other method.

```
$( "#foo" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );
```

So, I tried that in my code:

```
        $.each($children, function(key, value) {
            $(value).fadeIn("slow").delay(1000);
        });
```

However, that doesn't work for some reason. Everything fades in at the same time regardless of the time entered.

Comment: Well, what's a `delay` doing at the end of the chain? What do you want to happen exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop runs all at once, so specify different delays like 1000, 2000, 3000 etc..

The logic for that is `( 1000 * ( index + 1 ) )`, so for 0th you get `( 0 + 1 ) * 1000 === 1000`, for 1st you get `( 1 + 1 ) * 1000  === 2000` and so on

```
$.each($children, function(index, value) {
    $(value).delay(1000 * (index + 1)).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Oh and also... you must first delay before fade since you expect the delay to come before the fade

Comment: Ohhh... got it! That makes sense now! I was thinking that `delay` was kind of like `sleep` in other languages. So I was pretty confused as to what was going on. Thanks.